# attempt to call method 'find' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

attempt to call method 'find'(a nil value) in trAInsportedgame

```
function ai.foundPassengers(train, passengers)
    if train.passenger and train.passenger:find("Show me the money!") then return nil end

    for k, p in pairs(passengers) do
        print(p)
        if p.name:find("Show me the money!") then
            print("found VIP!")
            if train.passenger then
                dropPassenger(train)
            end
            return p
        end
    end
    return passengers[1]
end
```

Comment: what is your question? the error is quite clear. you're calling  a nil value. to avoid it, don't call a nil value

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! Please take a look into our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) including the article on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please note that actually asking a question will prove itself more efficient compared to not asking one (as Piglet already pointed out).

Comment: What is the `type(train.passenger)`?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Germanunkol/trAInsported/blob/e0ed49e73ffd447ba1024c8f08bcc0fb24bf3cdb/Scripts/ai.lua#L390

The code there suggests that `train.passenger` is a table, not a string.

As your table train.passenger does not implement a function `find` you cannot call it.

A few lines later you call `p.name:find("Show me the money!")` which to me doesn't make too much sense. Why would the name of a passenger contain "Show me the money!"?

passenger.name is a string. Maybe you intended to do the same above.